# jQuery multiple selectable listitem group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create multiple set of selectable list. 
jQueryUI [Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid).
Need help to separate the list in 2 set,  3 li in each set. The aim is to allow the user select only from the same set and each set should lay aside other.

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <!--set A -->
  <li class="ui-state-default">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">&nbsp;</li>
  <!--set B -->
  <li class="ui-state-default">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">&nbsp;</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what about throwing a identifier on the sets? then you're done, you just select what you want - `$('#setb').whatever() or $('#seta').whatever()`

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Omarjmh, I am newb, an example will help. Do u mean i need to assign id tag for different set?

Comment: fair enough, working on it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/9ur5xx4a/1/

Note that I didn't make the css the same, you'll have to do that part yourself.

The correct code is pretty straightforward, you need to just make two lists, then have a separate 'selectable' id on them like so:

**HTML**

```
    <ol id="selectable">
        <!--set A -->
        <li class="ui-state-default seta">Hello &nbsp;</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default seta">Hello &nbsp;</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default seta">Hello &nbsp;</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="selectable-1">
         <!--set B -->
        <li class="ui-state-default setb">Hello &nbsp;</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default setb">Hello &nbsp;</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default setb">Hello &nbsp;</li>
    </ol>
```

**JS**

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    $( "#selectable-1" ).selectable();

  });
```

That's it! With this you can select only one of the `<li>` tags in each list at a time. Now you can go make it pretty...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Omarjmh.  works exactly as expected. May i also know how to unselect the rest when i click on any set. unselecting method seems for a different purpose.